# How do I create an application that runs in the background and is interactive in Linux?

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks, daemon, audio

I want to create an application that runs in the background in Linux (daemon) that will basically at set times (5 times) play a music file or any sound given every single day. I want this daemon to start when the computer is started in terminal mode (non-GUI). I want to know if this is possible and if so, What considerations, tools, and programming language would be the most efficient in doing so? This will be a dedicated computer that will only be executing this task, so if any recommendations on how I can maximize efficiency while disabling other features that are not required for this task will be appreciated. Also, could you please explain how processes and tasks work in terminal (non-GUI)? I always thought terminal was something like CMD in Windows and can only run tasks one at a time.

EDIT: I need the sound to run at variable times, I'll be fetching these times from a website. Any suggestions regarding how to achieve this?

Thanks for the help and sorry for any shortcoming in the questions or my research.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using `cron` to run your tasks. `cron` is a very flexible scheduling utility built in to most Linux distributions.

Basically, with `cron` you specify a task to run (your main program, or maybe just a sound-playing program), all of its arguments, and when it runs. `cron` takes care of running it, and will even send you "mail" if the job produces any output (such as errors).

Comment: I need the sound to run at variable times, I'll be fetching these times from a website. Is chron able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make processes fork into a subprocess of your terminal, i.e. you are able to run more than one task at a time by putting a `&` after your terminal command:

```
> cmd&
> [you can type other commands here but the "cmd" program is still running]
```

However, for services you generally don't have to worry about starting it as a subprocess because the system already knows to do this. Here's [a good question from Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/663989/how-to-create-a-custom-service-that-will-autostart-on-boot-on-archlinux) that has an example of a working service. Simply place your service as a shell script in the `/etc/init.d` and it will be automatically started as a service.

Comment: I edited my question. I need the sound to run at variable times, I'll be fetching these times from a website. Am I able to do this by creating a simple script? Also, I don't see any links in your answer.

Comment: @Tech1337 Added the link. A service is always running in the background, so you would just have to have a polling function that looks at the website every x seconds and then play the sounds accordingly. Cron is usually used for programs that will run on a set schedule and then stop execution after their task is complete and is not ideal for your situation.